# MS Access 2013 Unbound TextBox Format:RichText displaying text and images

Tags: ms-access-2013

Is it possible to have an unbound Textbox, with the format of RichText, displaying text and images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the answer to this question is "No". A "Rich Text" Text Box can display formatted text, but not images.

You might be able to use a Web Browser Control to display text and images together.